# Java: Dice craps game with output not getting right

Tags: java

I'm working on a java program that will craps with two dice. I need to have the following:

- On the first roll, the player throws both 6-sided dice -
- The dice are summed together and if the sum is 7 or 11 on the first roll, the
  player wins
- If the sum of the first roll is 2, 3, or 12, the player
  loses
- Any other sum of the dice on the first roll become the player's
  point
- A player whos first roll was point must try to roll the same
  point again
- The player with point rolls continuously until one of two
  things happens
- If the player rolls the same point again, they win If
  the player rolls a 7, they lose

I can't get the it right, can someone provide some advice here please. Thansk

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Craps{
    public static void main(String [] args){ 

    int dice1 = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
    int dice2 = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
    int sum = dice1 + dice2;
    int point = sum;
    //int point = 
    System.out.printf("You rolled: %d %s %d %s %d\n",dice1,"+",dice2,"=",sum); 

     //for (sum = 1; sum >= 12; sum++){
     if ((sum == 7) || (sum == 11)){ 
     System.out.println("You Win!");
     return;}
     if ((sum == 2) || (sum == 3) || (sum == 12)){
     System.out.println("You Lose!");
     return;}
     while ((sum != 7) || (sum != 3) || (sum != 11) || (sum != 12)){
         System.out.printf("Your Point: %d\n", sum); 
         dice1 = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
         dice2 = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
         sum = dice1 + dice2;
         System.out.printf("You rolled: %d %s %d %s %d\n",dice1,"+",dice2,"=",sum);
         if (point == sum){ 
             System.out.println("You Win!");      
         }
         if (point == 7){
            System.out.println("You Lose!");
         }
         return; 
     }
     while (point != sum){
         System.out.printf("Your Point: %d\n", point);   

     return; 



     } 
   }
```

Following are a couple of games played for example output:

-C:\Users\javauser> java Craps
-You rolled 2 + 5 = 7
-You Win!

-C:\Users\javauser> java Craps
-You rolled 6 + 6 = 12
-You Lose!

-C:\Users\javauser> java Craps
-You rolled 4 + 5 = 9
-Your point is 9
-You rolled 2 + 3 = 5
-Your point is 9
-You rolled 5 + 5 = 10
-Your point is 9
-You rolled 5 + 4
-You Win!

-C:\Users\javauser> java Craps
-You rolled 4 + 4 = 8
-Your point is 8
-You rolled 3 + 4 = 7
-You lose!

Comment: You'll get more help if you provide a sample output of what you're getting and what you expect. Especially if you provide your thoughts on what is wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just finished editing the answer. Can give it a try and see if it works :) Hope it helps.

```
import java.util.Random; 

public class Craps{ public static void main(String [] args){

Boolean winLose = false;

int dice1 = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
int dice2 = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
int sum = dice1 + dice2;


if ((sum == 7) || (sum == 11)){ 
 System.out.println("You Win!");
 return;}

 else if ((sum == 2) || (sum == 3) || (sum == 12)){
 System.out.println("You Lose!");
 return;}

while(!winLose){
    System.out.printf("Your Point: %d\n", sum); 

    dice1 = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
    dice2 = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
    int point = dice1 + dice2;


    System.out.printf("You rolled: %d %s %d %s %d\n",dice1,"+",dice2,"=",point);
    if (point == sum){ 
        winLose = true;
        System.out.println("You Win!");      
    }
    if (point == 7){
        winLose = true;
        System.out.println("You Lose!");
    }

} 


.
.
.
.(complete the codes..)
```

Answer (score 0):

why not have

```
while (true) {

 System.out.printf("Your Point: %d\n", sum); 
 dice1 = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
 dice2 = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
 sum = dice1 + dice2;
 System.out.printf("You rolled: %d %s %d %s %d\n",dice1,"+",dice2,"=",sum);

 if (point == sum){ 
     System.out.println("You Win!");      
     break;
 }
 if (point == 7){
    System.out.println("You Lose!");
    break;
 }

 System.out.println("trying again");

}
```